ag grid selection change event gets triggered when I try to pre select the check boxes on load
So I am using 29.2.0 version for ag grid react.
I have to check the checkboxes under a certain condition and disable them on load that I have achieved.
The problem is now the Selection Changed Event gets triggered every time on the load.
I only want it to trigger when the user manually selects the checkbox.
here is my code
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
